# Select rows that are not present in the table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables student table and fee table:

First Table (Student):

| std_id | std_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

Second Table(Fee):

| fid | std_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 2 | 500 |
| 3 | 4 | 500 |

I want to fetch rows of those students from fee table who are not paid amount. In above example want to fetch the names of std_id 3,5 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common anti-semijoin.

Either

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (std_id)
WHERE t2.std_id IS NULL
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table2
                   WHERE table1.std_id = table2.std_id )
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE std_id NOT IN ( SELECT std_id 
                      FROM table2 )
```

First 2 variants have approximately the same effectiveness (depends on data statistic and indices presence, sometimes these queries may even produce the same execution plan). Last variant has least effectiveness approximately always.

Comment: Sir Akina! i have changed question, please guide now

Comment: No, once your question has been answered, it's not good manners to change it.

Comment: You can always post another question.